# What is the difference between $(document).ready(initialize) and $(document).on('ready', initialize)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the difference between:

```
$(document).ready(initialize);
```

and

```
$(document).on('ready', initialize);
```

To me they seem to work in the same way.

Comment: One uses a method directly, the other proxies through a helper method.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`$(document).on('ready',initialize);`  will not work if the DOM is already ready when the file is executed.

`$(document).ready()` has a special handling for this: it ensures it is always called

Comment: The latter is also unrelated to the contents of the jQuery object. So currently `$().ready()` and `$('foo').ready()` would be exactly the same thing.

Comment: for me it seems like people +1 voodoo answers they don't understand tbh

Answer (score 8):

### TL;DR

- `$(document).on('ready', ...)` is ***deprecated*** since it does not execute *callbacks* bound after the DOM was completely parsed. It gets event object as first argument.
- `$().ready()` gets passed a reference to `jQuery` as first argument.

---

## Detailed answer

> `$(document).on('ready', initialize);`

This expression is binding a `ready` event handler to `document`, like you would expect from any other *event handler*. Using this to listen to DOM ready is [deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) as of jQuery 1.8:

> There is also `$(document).bind("ready", handler)`, ***deprecated*** as of jQuery 1.8. This behaves similarly to the `ready` method but if the ready event has already fired and you try to `.bind("ready")` the bound handler will not be executed. Ready handlers bound this way are executed after any bound by the other three methods above.

Note that `ready` is a custom event, and triggered by jQuery [internally](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.8.3/src/core.js#L396). That also means that you can trigger it manually, which might mess things up.

---

> `$(document).ready(initialize);`

This expression does not really bind an event handler. [`jQuery.fn.ready`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.8.3/src/core.js#L230-235) is a dedicated method to **register callbacks** to be run when the DOM was completely parsed. jQuery is adding the callback to a *promise* object and it does not matter which selector you pass to `$`.

Additionally, the callback gets passed a reference to the jQuery object instead of an *event* object.

---

The follwoing part of the [source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.8.3/src/core.js#L391-397) nicely shows that callbacks registered like this are handled differently:

```
// If there are functions bound, to execute
readyList.resolveWith(document, [jQuery]);

// Trigger any bound ready events
if (jQuery.fn.trigger) {
    jQuery(document).trigger("ready").off("ready");
}
```