# Differences between $(document).ready(function(){}) and $(document).on('ready', function(e)

Tags: jquery

I see many projects using

```
$(document).on('ready', function(e){
 //jquery stuff
})
```

Instead of:

```
$( document ).ready(function(  ) {
  // Code using $ as usual goes here.
});
```

or

```
 $(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
 });
```

I read the complete [api documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)  but I don't see what is the case of use of the first example.

For me, the use of `on` in the first example is useless.

What are the differences between the cases?

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13589307/what-is-the-difference-between-document-readyinitialize-and-document-on

Comment: You should be using the latest JQuery ready syntax anyway i.e.: `$(function() {
  // Code using $ as usual goes here. });` :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The function:

```
$( document ).ready(function ( ) {
  // Code using $ as usual goes here.
});
```

Translates to:

```
$( document ).on( 'ready', function (e) {
 //jquery stuff
})
```

This is the same with these shorthand functions:

```
$( element ).click( function ( ) { } );
$( element ).hover( function ( ) { } );
$( element ).load( function ( ) { } );
$( element ).scroll( function ( ) { } );
```

From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/click/) of `.click( handler(eventObject) )`:

> This method is a shortcut for `.on( "click", handler )` in the first two variations, and `.trigger( "click" )` in the third.

---

**Updated Answer - The difference!**

> There is also `$(document).on( "ready", handler )`, *deprecated as of
>   jQuery 1.8*. This behaves similarly to the ready method but if the
>   ready event has already fired and you try to `.on( "ready" )` the bound
>   handler will not be executed. Ready handlers bound this way are
>   executed after any bound by the other three methods above.

-- [*Source*](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)

**Update #2**

`jQuery(function(){});`

should also be considered as a shorter alternative to

`jQuery(document).ready(function(){});`

It is genuinely prefered since it does not reduce readability and removes a few bytes of character.

Comment: Don't forget to add the callbacks, otherwise it will be interpreted as a trigger. ;-)

Comment: Then are both the same thing?

Comment: @EmilioGort No difference. `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar in this question they say that aren't the same..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13589307/what-is-the-difference-between-document-readyinitialize-and-document-on

Comment: Why wouldn't you use `jQuery(function(){})`?

Comment: @PhilippeTrépanier I don't get you. Why not? Both are the same. `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar My point exactly, except this variation is more compact... Just wondering why you didnt point it out as a variation. :P

Comment: @PhilippeTrépanier Yeah. Kinda... Well, can you help me out to update the answer? TIA.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Done, yw!